# Laravel nova create blank page without show row table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

i am trying to create a page using laravel nova that only show 3 chart without displaying table or row data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nHDv.png)

is it can be using nova resource or nova tools ?

or any other thing ?

Comment: Either a [Tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/tools.html) or a [Custom Dashboard](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/dashboards.html)

Comment: actually i tried to create a menu named "Report" and it has 2 submenus.

Report
--- Transaction
--- User

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed this using :

- [nova dashboard](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/dashboards.html#defining-dashboards) `php artisan nova:dashboard TransactionReportDashboard`
- [create custom card](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/cards.html#defining-cards) `php artisan nova:card vendor/package-name`
- and i use [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/)

[see the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fuz.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use new dashboard for this perpos
check here https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/#resource-events